# Getting the character from keyup event

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

I'm handling the keyup event, and need to get the character being typed. When I type a dot, data.keyCode is 190, but when I'm trying to convert it using String.fromCharCode(190), I'm getting the "¾" symbol.

[This reference](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx) tells me 190 is the period symbol. [That one](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) says I don't have any chance for cross-browser keypress handling. So, how do I handle this properly?

Comment: Do you want to get only typed character code using keyUp or wants to perform some action/validation once you get code

Comment: I just want to send it to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm handling the keyup event, and need to get the character being typed.

That's not reliably available. On `keyup` you only get the `keyCode` and not the `charCode`.

(If you think about it this makes sense: the `charCode` is associated with the character being typed in a keypress, which might be shifted with a modifier key and so generate a different character to the base key; on `keyup` and `keydown`, since those events are not immediately associated with a new character being typed, there isn't a known character to generate.)

So if you are doing something that relies on knowing whether a `.` *character* was typed, you will need to use the `keypress` event instead.

If you want to know when the abstract *key* that is labelled `.`/`>` on some common keyboard layouts is released, you can do that with `keyup`, using the `keyCode` listed on the unixpapa link. Using `keyCode` like this is typically used for games and other features where the actual key position matters rather than the character it generates when typed.

Unfortunately the browsers have made an inconsistent mess of some keyCodes including this one, so you'd have to check it for all possible values listed above, and you can't reliably tell the difference between the main keyboard period, the numpad period/delete key and the main delete key.